# How to correctly use Pandas iterators for hdf5?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an HDF5 file that I am simply trying to read the data in chunks and output to a mySQL table.

Using pandas v. 0.12.0
Code looks like,

```
iter = store.select('data',iterator=True, chunksize=5000)
for data in iter:
    # write the data out
```

But I get an exception:

```
for data in iter:
  File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 969, in __iter__
  v = self.func(current, stop)
  File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 451, in func
    return s.read(where=where, start=_start, stop=_stop, columns=columns, **kwargs)
  File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3175, in read

    mgr = BlockManager([block], [cols_, index_])
  File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1001, in __init__
    self._verify_integrity()
  File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1239, in _verify_integrity
construction_error(tot_items,block.values.shape[1:],self.axes)
  File "d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2216, in construction_error
tuple(map(int, [len(ax) for ax in axes]))))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5000), indices imply (1, 3751044)
```

I don't understand what the error is trying to say, ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 5000), indices imply (1, 3751044). And I don't know how to make it happy.

I thought that the chunksize=5000 value would tell pandas to read the data in 5000 row chunks, but apparently it does not like that doing the iteration. What is the correct usage of the select(chunksize=XXXX)?

Comment: this has a number of bugs in the iterator < 0.14, so I would recommend that you upgrade to the current, 0.15.1; Your usage looks correct though. docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterator). FYI, you HAVE to use a ``table`` format to store the data. The ``fixed`` format does not support iteration (I believe in 0.13 we started using this nomenclature)

Comment: Thanks. Upgraded to 0.15.1, same error. This time I noticed that I get an incompatibility warnning: 
d:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:2966: IncompatibilityWarning
:
where criteria is being ignored as this version [0.0.0] is too old (or
not-defined), read the file in and write it out to a new file to upgrade (with
the copy_to method)

What copy_to method is this referring to?

Comment: hmm, you have a really old version (and that warning is probably a bit dated). You need to show more of what you have. Can you read the file in a ``select()``? (no iterator)?

Comment: No luck with several tries. This HDF5 was created directly with pytables, so maybe I will just drop back to pytables and read the arrays there and use pandas to write to SQL. Thanks.

Comment: that would have been important to mention; pandas can read a native PyTables table but as there is no meta data queries are not directly possible

Comment: OK. It might be nice to mention no Pandas meta means no Pandas query in the docs. I saw the mention of earlier versions get met with a deprecated warning.

Answer (score 1):

I hate answering my own question, but to help someone else that might come along later with the same problem here goes.

As Jeff mentioned, there is no pandas metadata in the PyTables HDF5 file on disk. So what I did instead:

```
h5file = tables.open_file(file, mode="r")
signal_data = h5file.root.signal_data
data_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(signal_data)
```

Now I can manipulate data_frame in Pandas as needed.

Thanks to [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644898/jeff) for the help.